# Checking duplicate record, while inserting multiple row in Mysql DB in Php

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I would like to know , how can I check duplicate record, while adding multiple row in Mysql DB in Php?

I'm adding data to my DB from excel sheet using php reader.

Here is my code, what I've tried so far, but its always adding duplicate row without giving any notification/error message.

```
            $x=2;
        while($x<=$connection->sheets[$sheet]['numRows']) {//04     
        $bpsuplier = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][1]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][1] : '';
        $borp = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][2]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][2] : '';
        $bpslno = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][3]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][3] : '';
        $bptype = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][4]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][4] : '';
        $bprefno = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][5]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][5] : '';
        $bpdate = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][6]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][6] : '';
        $bpamnt = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][7]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][7] : '';
        $bpcurr = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][8])? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][8] : '';
        $bpkcgmt = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][9]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][9] : '';
        $bpkcgmtfor = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][10]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][10] : '';
        $bprmks = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][11]) ? $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][11] : '';

//======================section-001-->check duplicate=====
$res= mysqli_query($conn,"select * from account where 
factsuply='$bpsuplier'  and billpay='$borp'     and bpslno='$bpslno'    and bpdtyp='$bptype'    and bprefno='$bprefno' and bpdte='$bpdate'  and ackcgmt='$bpkcgmt'  and bpprog='$bpkcgmtfor'    and acamount='$bpamnt'  and currency='$bpcurr'  and acrmks='$bprmks' ");
 $total = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if($total==0)
//======================section-001-->check duplicate=====
  { 
$insert = $conn->prepare('
INSERT INTO account (factsuply, billpay, bpslno, bpdtyp, bprefno, bpdte, 
    ackcgmt, bpprog, acamount, currency, acrmks ) 
    VALUES (
    ?, ?, ?, ?,
    ?, ?, ?, ?,
    ?, ?, ?)
   ');
  $insert->bind_param(
   'sssssssssss',
  $bpsuplier, $borp, $bpslno, $bptype,
  $bprefno, $bpdate, $bpamnt, $bpcurr,
  $bpkcgmt, $bpkcgmtfor, $bprmks );
  $insert->execute();           
  $x++;


 //======================section-001-->message for duplicate entry=====
}
else
 {
   echo "This is seems DUPLICATE entry, please go back 
  and do some changes to add new entry.";
 }
 //======================section-001-->message for duplicate entry=====

}//04-x2numrows
```

Comment: suggest you add debug code to print out the Select statement,try inserting a row you know exists, then then run the SQL directly on the database, see if it returns anything.

Comment: One option, which might not work for you is REPLACE INTO. If the record already exists it will update the existing record. But again, that might not be what you are looking for judging by your PHP code.

Comment: What happens if you change `$x=2;` to `$x=1;`, why are you using a while loop and not a foreach? Perhaps also loop over the sheet cells 1-11, build an array and use that with the queries, way too many single use variables.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone $x=1; is containing the heading, that's not the problem. I believe. Can you give any example to use the foreach in my code?